# Dynamically add a shape / mask to an inline svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, svg-animate

I have a site with a series of elements that, when clicked on, add inline svg code to that element. The svg essentially animates an "iris wipe" to tunr the element white. Code from a separate html document is the loaded into a series of divs. When all the images are done loading, I want to append a mask to the svg code to iris wipe it back to how it was.

I am using [waitForImages.js](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) to check when the images are done loading. This is working successfully. The mask is also being added to the svg correctly. However, the mask animates.

Here is the initial code for adding the svg:

```
$("#selProject").append('<svg id="circleCont" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 360 360" enable-background="new 0 0 360 360"><circle class="circ" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.01" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"><animate attributeName="r" from="0.01" to="100%" dur="0.2" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/><animate attributeName="stroke-width" from="0.5" to="100" dur="0.2" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/></circle><circle class="circ" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.01" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"><animate attributeName="r" from="0.01" to="100%" dur="0.2" begin="0.1s" fill="freeze"/><animate attributeName="stroke-width" from="0.5" to="200" dur="0.2" begin="0.1s" fill="freeze"/></circle><circle class="circ" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.01" fill="#FFFFFF" mask="url(#mask1)"><animate attributeName="r" from="0.01" to="100%" dur="0.3" begin="0.2s" fill="freeze"/></circle></svg>')
```

This is probably not the cleanest way to do it, but is the way I knew how.

Later, after some other code / loading the other html document using ajax

```
$("#selProject").waitForImages(function() {
    $("#projectPageInfo").waitForImages(function() {
        $("svg").append('<mask id="mask1"><rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" /><circle id="circmask" class="circ" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="0.01" fill="#000000"><animate attributeName="r" from="0.01" to="100%" dur="0.3" begin="0s" fill="freeze"/></circle></mask>');
    });
});
```

The mask worked correctly when it was apart of the initial svg code being added, and animated as it should have. However, I needed it not to happen until the images have loaded, and now, despite the mask being added to the svg successfully, it does not animate. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's the typical jQuery problem.  JQuery cannot be relied on to do the right thing with SVG elements.  jQuery is designed to work with HTML, not SVG whose elements are in a different namespace.

The first append works because the browser knows what to do with the `<svg>` element, and does the right thing.  However the second append fails because the `<mask>` element will be created in the default (ie. HTML) namespace rather than the SVG one.

If you look at the DOM properties of the appended `<mask>` element in your browser's dev tools, you will probably find that it has the wrong (ie. not SVG) namespace.

As a solution, I would try adding the `<mask>` back in to the original SVG and only set the `mask` attribute when you want the mask to be used.  In other words, remove:

```
mask="url(#mask1)"
```

then when you want the mask to be applied:

```
document.getElementById("id-of-masked-circle").setAttribute("mask", "url(#mask1)");
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by "set the `mask` attribute"?